# NodeJS res.status is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Im using pg to connect to a postgres database and running this code:

```
const text = 'SELECT table($1, $2)'
const values = ['2019-12-04', 1]

config.client.query(text, values)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.rows[0])
        res.status(200)
        res.send('ok')
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e.stack))
```

I get the following error: res.status is not a function. How can i fix this?

Comment: `res` refers to a postgres result. You seem to be confusing that with the *response* object used by frameworks like Express…?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `res` is the DB response, but you have to use the `express router resp` to send response as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, expressRes)
{
const text = 'SELECT table($1, $2)'
const values = ['2019-12-04', 1]

config.client.query(text, values)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.rows[0])
        expressRes.status(200)
        expressRes.send('ok')
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e.stack))
});
```